# Flutter web: Store a CSV file to Firebase Storage without uploading it from the computer

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I'm trying to transform a Flutter mobile application into to a Flutter web application. In the Flutter application I generated a csv file, stored it in the memory of the phone and then uploaded it to Firebase storage, here is a snippet of the relevant code:

```
//relevant imports:
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart' as path_provider;
import 'package:csv/csv.dart';

//relevant code
Future writeCSV(..) async{
    final _storage = FirebaseStorage.instance;
    List<List> names = [];
    //...
    //Store data in the list 'names'
    //....
    final directory = await path_provider.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File file = await File('${directory.path}/data.csv').create();

    String csv = const ListToCsvConverter().convert(names);
    await file.writeAsString(csv);
    var snapshot = await _storage.ref().child('data2.csv').putFile(file).onComplete;
}
```

How could one go about this in Flutter web? When I tried to search for solutions, I could only find examples where you uploaded the file from the computer, but I would like to generate the file directly and then upload it to Firebase storage

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this in the following manner:

```
import 'dart:html';
import 'package:firebase/firebase.dart' as fb;
//..
//..
String data = 'name,city,age\nSimon,London,30\nJohn,New York,40';
final path = 'data.csv';
var file_contents = <String>[data];
var blob = Blob(file_contents, 'text/csv', 'native');
fb.storage().refFromURL('gs://<name>.appspot.com/')
.child(path).put(blob);
```